# Why does cloning a repo from MicroSoft Azure DevOps create a directory name containing %20 instead of a whitespace?

Tags: azure-devops

I have cloned a Repo from MicroSoft Azure DevOps to my local machine using Visual Studio 2022.

The path to the local repo contains a directory name for the DevOps project containing %20 instead of a whitespace.

As a consequence builds fail as reference paths in the solution and project files use whitespaces.

There is a way round is by removing the %20 from the directory name locally but it should be possible the build projects and solutions direct from cloning them without any other intervention so I'd like to find out if there is some way of acheivingthat.

Anyone got any advice on that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not an answer to your question but you would have less issues by not using a space in the path, but using an underscore instead.